# How to set Compilation directives for windows phone 8.1 project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, conditional-compilation

How to set Compilation directives for windows phone 8.1 project ?
If i add new configuration in configuration manager how it use in code?
Because its not work.
Example:

```
string myStringItem="";
#if MyFirstConfig
myStringItem="FirstString";
#endif
#if MySecondConfig
myStringItem="SecondString";
#endif
```

It does not work if I choose MyFirstConfig in the configuration manager, or if I choose MySecondConfig, does not work either. Why? How to do it correctly?
Running last assignment, no matter what the chosen configuration. What to do?

Comment: Are you defining those variables in the project settings of each configuration?

Comment: wow. thank you.About it I completely forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit them in your Build settings in each project.

[image]